# java.net.socketexception: too many files open, /tmp/imageio2002515050983683549.tmp

Tags: java, linux, sockets, debian

After running one of my java programs on Debian for about more than 30 hours or so I get "java.net.socketexception: too many files open".

I used the command below to find the open sockets

```
lsof -P -n -p 4910
```

After running it for a few hours I can see many open sockets such as below

```
/tmp/imageio2002515050983683549.tmp
/tmp/imageio996828308430904152.tmp
/tmp/imageio5844657308570033292.tmp
```

What can the sockets above be related to? there is a method in my program which writes text on images and here is the code. Could this method be creating those sockets and not closing them?

```
public String writeTextOnImage(String imagePath, String text) throws Exception
{
    int x = 30;
    int y = 300;

    String editedImageName = Tools.GenerateRandomString() + ".jpg";

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

    // draw graphics
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
    g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
g2d.drawString(text , x, y);

    g2d.dispose();

    File file = new File(editedImageName);
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", file);

    return editedImageName;
}
```

If anyone can point in the right direction as what can be creating these sockets, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably be closing the file when you're done with it..

Comment: Are you sure this is the only place where you deal with these files? I would expect `ImageIO` to be sufficiently well written to not leak file descriptors. The leak is probably elsewhere.

Comment: I run the same app on windows and I don't get that error. I checked the third party code and it has no problems. Could this be a bug in Java? is there any alternative to "lsof -P -n -p 4910" on windows so I can see if they are also being left open forever?